# Validation JSON response for a Laravel API controller

Tags: php, laravel

Assume I have a controller that's responsible for an API web service in my Laravel 8 application. What is my option for returning the correct HTTP response/error message(s) using the `Validator` facade?

```
   public function __invoke(Request $request)
   {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_id' => 'required|digits'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                
            ]);
        }

    }
```

In this case, if `user_id` is missing from the request body, I want to return a JSON response using the error message built into `$validator` with an HTTP 4xx? (I believe 400 in the case of a Bad Request, missing required parameter). I do not want to redirect here, just return an HTTP 400 with the error messages as a JSON response. How do I do that in Laravel 8.x?

Comment: if your request is sending the appropriate "accept" header for JSON you can just call `validate` and it will throw an exception that will cause the exception handler to return the messages as JSON, validation uses the 422 code

Comment: @lagbox the problem is, I cannot rely on every client to set proper headers

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: you can also force this header into requests if you wanted via a middleware, so the framework thinks all requests to the api are accepting json

Comment: have you try to put the ```Route``` inside ```api.php``` incoming request there already have api middleware set in the ```App\Http\Kernel.middlewareGroups```